# how to refresh depending ng-tabs with Angular 6

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I use [ng-boostrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) to display tabs with Angular 6.

I have 2 tabs, Categories and Categories Settings.

In Categories, I can add or remove categories. In CategoriesSettings, I can configure each category.

This is if I add / remove a category, and then go to categoriesSettings, I get an error:

```
NgbTabset.html:4 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'active: false'. Current value: 'active: true'.
```

Which I could understand, because I changed the value of Categories Array in another tab.

Error message is not telling me about Categories Array but about a boolean called active which allows me to remember active tab.

Also, each tab is a different component.

How should I do it?

Here is a bit of code:

```
<ngb-tabset type="pills" class="nav-fill" #tabs [activeId]="selectedTab" >
    <ngb-tab id="categories">
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>{{ 'model.categories' | translate | uppercase }}</ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-body">
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitCategories()">
                <app-tournament-edit-categories
                [(ngModel)]="data.tournament" name="tournament"
                [tournament]="data.tournament"
                [categories]="data.categories">
                </app-tournament-edit-categories>
                <div align="right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    {{ 'common.save' | translate }}
                </button>
                </div>

            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab id="category-settings">
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>{{ 'model.categorySettings' | translate | uppercase }}</ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-body">
            <!--TODO When clicked, must refresh the page, as it could be changed with edit categories page-->
            <app-tournament-edit-category-settings
                *ngFor="let championship of data.tournament.championships; index as i"
                [championship]="championship"
                [i]="i"
            >
            </app-tournament-edit-category-settings>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ng-tabset>
```

Do you need to see components ?